# Double naming in classname

Tags: php, oop, naming

I cannot sleep :)

Does a classname with double naming violate any standards or coding rules like Psr? I'm asking, because I cannot find any information about it..

Naming example:

```
MyFramwork\Logger\Logger
```

PHP example:

```
namespace MyFramework\Logger;

class Logger {
     // Do something
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't violate the standards, but I would not do this to avoid confusion.
Instead you can have `MyFramework\Logging\Logger.php` or something like`MyFramework\Loggers\FileLogger.php`.

But in general, I see such cases (same namespace and class name) in popular frameworks, like [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php) and [Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n/blob/master/src/Translator/Translator.php). So you can sleep well.